# Convergence of the sequence $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\bigg(1-\frac{bc}{n}\bigg)^{2(n-j)}\frac{c}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

I would like to prove (or disprove) the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{c}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\bigg(1-\frac{bc}{n}\bigg)^{2(n-j)}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{1}{2b}(1-e^{-2bc})$$
for $b,c>0$. After using the results on the geometric series I got stuck on

$$\frac{c}{n}\frac{\bigg(1-\frac{bc}{n}\bigg)^{2n}-1}{\bigg(1-\frac{bc}{n}\bigg)^{2}-1}$$

and at the moment I don't know how to continue. Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x=\frac{bc}{n}$. Then $n=\frac{bc}{x}$ and $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$. Moreover, $$\frac{x}{(x-1)^2-1}\longrightarrow -\frac{1}{2}$$ $$(1-x)^{\frac{2bc}{x}}\longrightarrow e^{-2bc}$$ as $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$. Therefore $$\frac{c}{n}\frac{\bigg(1-\frac{bc}{n}\bigg)^{2n}-1}{\bigg(1-\frac{bc}{n}\bigg)^{2}-1}=\frac{x}{(x-1)^2-1}\cdot \frac{1}{b}\cdot \Bigg[(1-x)^{\frac{2bc}{x}}-1\Bigg]\longrightarrow -\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{b}\cdot \Big[e^{-2bc}-1\Big]$$

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative we have

$$\frac{c}{n}\frac{\bigg(1-\frac{bc}{n}\bigg)^{2n}-1}{\bigg(1-\frac{bc}{n}\bigg)^{2}-1}=
\frac{c}{n}
\frac{\bigg(1-\frac{bc}{n}\bigg)^{2n}-1}
{\left(1-\frac{bc}{n}+1\right)\left(1-\frac{bc}{n}-1\right)}=$$
$$=-\frac n{bc}\frac{c}{n}
\frac{\bigg(1-\frac{bc}{n}\bigg)^{2n}-1}
{\left(2-\frac{bc}{n}\right)}\to -\frac{1}{2b}(e^{-2bc}-1)$$