# Prove or disprove limit of infinite product with nested sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, infinite-product

This question is related to [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262066/convergence-of-the-sequence-sum-j-1n-bigg1-fracbcn-bigg2n-j-f). I would like to see now if the following holds:
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\bigg(1-\frac{a\frac{c}{n}(1-\frac{bc}{n})^{2(n-k)}}{2}\bigg)\stackrel{?}{\to}e^{-\frac{a}{4b}(1-e^{-2bc})}$$
for $a,b,c>0$. From the other question, we know that
$$h_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{c}{n}\bigg(1-\frac{bc}{n}\bigg)^{2(n-k)}\to \frac{1}{2b}(1-e^{-2bc})$$
The limit above feels legit to me because it bears similarity with the sequence converging to $e$, but it may as well be untrue, or true under some conditions. However, I don't know how to evaluate that infinite product because taking logs should be out of the question. Any help super appreciated, especially references on how to evaluate such infinite products with sequences inside (any theorem?).

---

**UPDATE:** numerical results point towards the fact that the limit holds, but I am still unable to find a proof.

Answer (score 1):

I will sketch the proof of a more general result. Firstly, observe that simply by reordering each (finite) sum, we can write, for example:

$$h_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{c}{n} \bigg(1 - \frac{bc}{n}\bigg)^{2k}$$

Perhaps this is just a matter of preference, but I think, psychologically, it is beneficial for the index of the sum to correspond to the summand in this more direct way. In any case, this is the form in which I will prove the result.

**Proposition**

Let $s_n$ be a sequence given by $s_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_{k,n}$, where $a_{k,n} \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ are uniformly $\mathcal{O}(n^{-1})$* for each $k$ (i.e. there exists some $C>0$ such that $|a_{k,n}| < \frac{C}{n}$ for every $k$ given $n$ sufficiently large).

Suppose that $s_n \to s$. Then, $p_n := \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-a_{k,n}) \to e^{-s}$.

(*Note that this condition is met for your sequence as $a,b,c$ are constants.)

**Proof**

Consider $l_n := \ln(p_n)$.

$$\implies l_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \ln(1-a_{k,n})$$

We may find $N$ sufficiently large such that $|a_{k,N}| < 1$ for all $n \ge N$, since the $a_{k,n}$ are uniformly $\mathcal{O}(n^{-1})$ for each $k$. WLOG let $N = 0$ since we are only concerned with the limiting behaviour as $n \to \infty$ anyway. Now, we may quote the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1-u)$ to find that:

$$l_n = - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \bigg( a_{k,n} + \frac{a_{k,n}^2}{2} + \cdots \bigg)$$

But for each $k$, the $a_{k,n}$ are $\mathcal{O}(n^{-1})$ and we are only adding $\mathcal{O}(n)$ terms for each $l_n$, so we find that:

$$l_n = \bigg(- \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_{k,n} \bigg) + \mathcal{O}(n^{-1})$$

(Note that since every term inside the earlier sum was positive, we did not have to worry about any ill effects from rearranging the terms.)

$$\implies l_n \to -s$$

$$\implies p_n \to e^{-s}$$

by the continuity of $\text{exp}$. $\square$

---

I wrote this quite quickly, so there may be errors. Please feel free to point out any that you find; I am keen to be a respectable, helpful and important contributor, and I have no trouble acknowledging my mistakes.